# Xcode 9.2 upgrade results in this error: "Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1"

Tags: ios, swift, crash, upgrade, xcode9

After upgrading to **Xcode 9.2** this error appears in all of my projects:

> Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1

[image]

Error actually appears when running on a real device, but in simulator it runs normally.

Anyone has a solution?

Comment: i have tried soltion to remove derived data also clean but not working :/

Comment: Which dependency manager are you using? If you are using Carthage it is possible that you have a duplicated reference in your embedded frameworks.

Comment: no , i have not use Carthage :/

Comment: Finalllllly :D , I SOLVED issues if any one this issue face like me on xCode 9.2 

Go to ~/Library/Keychains delete this Folder and install Xcode Again 

Thank you for all of you with support

Answer (score 0):

- try to remove the derived data(from trash too)
- product clean (cmd+shift+k)
- restart the Xcode

Comment: no error actually appear when run on real device but on simulator run normally

Comment: May be your Alamofire framework is just only built for real devices. For simulators needs a separate framework(simulators architecture is different). Check your framework

Comment: i don't think so as in project have many frame work not only alamofire

Comment: just remove and add the frameworks again. If you're using pod, execute pod install

Comment: Finalllllly :D , I SOLVED issues if any one this issue face like me on xCode 9.2 

Go to ~/Library/Keychains delete this Folder and install Xcode Again 

Thank you for all of you with support